# How to change the text colour of Android Notification

Tags: android, android-notifications

We are using **Foreground Service** with Notification. A very simple use-case requires us to change the text-colour of the notification's body and title text. After a quick search, I was enlighten with `setColor()` method of `NotificationCompat.Builder`.

However, using it only changes the tint colour of the small icon and not the notification title or body text. I also wanted the text ***0/7 files have been uploaded and 7 pending*** to be coloured desirably. This is how it looks currently,

[image]

How can I change the text colour of the notification title and body text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't change this, this is system style for `Notification`, don't have option for setting text color... but you can introduce your [own layout](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/custom-notification) for this purpose, but be aware that across different Android distributions there are different default `Notification` styles (made by manufacturers) and you won't provide one universal style with only-text-color-changed style, which will fit into system styling (same look as other notifications)